# add_action is not working in another function for admin notice

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created **[custom divi module](https://github.com/angelleye/divi-paypal/tree/dev)** and then convert it to the **plugin**.
Now I want to **active plugin only if Divi theme is activated**.
when i write code like this way it shows notice everytime.

```
function my_admin_notice(){
    echo '<div class="updated">
       <p>test Admin notice.</p>
    </div>';
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```

But when I write code with conditions based

```
    function angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install()
    {    
        if (function_exists('et_setup_theme')) {
            // Divi is the current theme or the active theme's parent.
            // trigger our function that registers PayPal for Divi plugin.     
            angelleye_setup_for_paypal_divi();          
        }
        else{
             // code when theme is not activated.
             add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
        }            
    }
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install' );

 function my_admin_notice(){
        echo '<div class="updated">
           <p>test Admin notice.</p>
        </div>';
    }
```

I copied code for showing admin notice here https://wptheming.com/2011/08/admin-notices-in-wordpress/

Now add_action I am calling in function **angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install**
But in the function add_action is not working,.

Comment: I think that your `add_action` is working but there is a problem within that `add_action function`. Try `echo Hello World;` before implementing logic within the function. If you see hello world then the add_action is working but there is a problem with the logic you are implementing

Comment: @FahadSohail Check my code now.

Comment: @FahadSohail I only write echo and it is also not  calling function :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding condition in wrong place. Please remove condition from here.

```
/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
  * 
  */
function angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install()
{   

angelleye_setup_for_paypal_divi();

} 
      register_activation_hook( __FILE__,'angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install' );
```

Add this code after activation function for display admin notice

```
/* Display a notice that can be dismissed */
function my_custom_notice() {
 ?>
 <div class="update-nag notice">
  <p><?php _e( 'Please install Divi theme to use PayPal Divi Module!', 'angelleye_paypal_divi' ); ?></p>
 </div>
 <?php
}
$theme = wp_get_theme();
if($theme != 'Divi' ) {
 add_action( 'admin_notices', 'my_custom_notice' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are missing two requirements of admin notices `{class}`and `{message}` as mentioned in https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices

try

```
function angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install()
{    
    if (function_exists('et_setup_theme')) {
        // Divi is the current theme or the active theme's parent.
        // trigger our function that registers PayPal for Divi plugin.     
        angelleye_setup_for_paypal_divi();          
    }
    else{
         // code when theme is not activated.
         add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success' );
    }            
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install' );

function sample_admin_notice__success() {
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i copied your code and change it same as yours but still add_action is not calling. My issue is exactly that. I have die() in the function too but its not calling so die() will not execute. but if i put echo in the if else condition then it print that echo with fatal error.

Comment: umm.. Try declaring the `sample_admin_notice__success` function above the `angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install` function

Comment: Tried it. 
still not calling the function.

Comment: when i put `add_action('admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success');` above `angelleye_setup_For_paypal_divi_install` it is showing notification on every page of admin.

Comment: and you want it on a specific page? A simple conditional can work to check and verify if it is your required page then display the notice or dont..

Comment: So previously the problem we were facing was that the function wasn't responding but that has been solved but now we're seeing the message at wrong pages right? 

On which page of the dashboard do you want the message to show?

Comment: function is still not calling